# Magento 1.9 : How to Edit the price of all products؟

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, catalog

I want to increase the price of all products
And if I want to edit each one
It's very time consuming
Is there a way to group?

Comment: You may do it programmatically. Do you want to increase the price by a fixed amount or by a certain percentage? Or Do you have the updated prices in a CSV file ? Please clarify, I will provide a shell script to update the prices programmatically based on your needs.

Comment: If your products have the same price (I don't think so) you can use the massAction via admin to do that otherwise, you have to it manually

Comment: I want to raise all the products for a certain amount

Answer (score 1):

1. Export all products from admin

[image]
[image]

2. Then copy complete sku column from this export csv.
3. Create new csv with 2 columns (sku , price ). paste all sku on that new csv and add updated price on price column and make import that csv .

4.Import from admin->system->importexport->import
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can alternately use this solution. A bit of programming is required .Create this file in your Magento root folder

```
require_once('/app/Mage.php'); //path to mage bootstrapper

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 

$csvObject = new Varien_File_Csv();

$pathtoCSV = '/path/products.csv';
$data =  $csvObject->getData($pathtoCSV);

foreach ($data as $lines => $line) {
    $sku = trim($line[0]);
    $price = trim($line[1]);

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));

    $product->setPrice($price);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'price');

 }
```

Comment: What's the file name؟

Comment: You can give any name as it is just a php file accessing core magento functions through the Mage.php